# Getting nil on Core Data relationship save

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to save one side of a one to many relationship (one company can have many opportunities) and using dot syntax to save the fields.

The intent when I save this record is to add a new opportunity and to update the set of opportunities on the company record.

I believe core data should take care of all that but when I save the record and retrieve it, the opportunity name comes back fine but the company name is set to a nil and it crashes. Here is my save code - can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
func saveViaCoAgain() {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!

        var newOpp: Opportunity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Opportunity", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Opportunity
        newOpp.oppName = passedOppName
        newOpp.company.companyName = passedCoName

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {
            abort()
        }
}
```

Comment: `newOpp.company` is `nil` for the newly created object. You probably want `newOpp.company = existingCompany` where the latter is a Company object.

Comment: Thanks. How do I create an existing company without using "insertnewobject"? If I do that it all works but creates an opportunity record and a company record - and what I want is for the opportunity to be added to the set against an existing company.

Comment: So I think the question is whether there is a different way to initialize a company object?

Comment: Or maybe I am misunderstanding how core data would store these things.  I had assumed a one to many would have one record for company, with pointers to multiple opportunity records. Would it in fact have one record for every opportunity? If so that would explain why I am seeing multiple companies in my company table view list. Can you clarify

Comment: If you want to add the opportunity to an existing company (and you don't have a pointer to the company object) then you have to execute a *fetch request* to get the company object, e.g. a fetch request with a *predicate* that retrieves the company with the given name.

Comment: Thank you - that is completely correct and works fine. I appreciate the help.